# How to set maxlength for lightning-input-rich-text

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput, lightning-components, inputrichtext

How can we limit the number of characters entered in rich text field lightning field

```
<lightning-input-rich-text
        value={myVal}>
    </lightning-input-rich-text>
```

Is there any provision to provide maxlength so that user cannot enter anything more than specified number of characters; I dont see anything in the documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-rich-text/specification

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As you said, there is no attribute for what you want. Within that same documentation is the following

> **lightning-input-rich-text doesn't provide built-in validation but you can wire up your own validation**. Set the valid attribute to
> false to change the border color of the rich text editor to red. Set
> the required and label-visible attributes to display the asterisk near
> the label.

So you'll have to wire up your own logic to check the length of the value within the input

```
<template>
    <lightning-input-rich-text
        value={myVal}
        message-when-bad-input={errorMessage}
        valid={validity}>
    </lightning-input-rich-text>
</template>
```

within your js, you can do it on a button (if it's to be submitted) or on the change `onchange` within the input

```
onSubmit(){
    if(this.myVal.length > 300){
        this.validity = false;
        this.errorMessage = "You have exceeded the max length";
    } else {
        //submit
    }
}
```